# CSS only loads for one out of two ejs files despite partials and public folder being set up properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I have two EJS files set up using header and footer partials, with CSS linked properly using static public folder like so:
`app.use(express.static("public"))`

The CSS is linked properly as the styling shows up on the index.js page when it's loaded. However when I make a request for the show.ejs, the html shows up so I know there's no issue, only there's no styling. What is going on? I have checked for errors in the layout but it's correct as the page loads so I'm at a loss.

Header partial EJS file: header.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your page title here :)</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>
```

First EJS file: index.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header');-%>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 10%">
      <h4>Budget</h4>
      <table>
        <% budgetAll.forEach( (budgetItem, index) => { %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= budgetItem.date %></td>
          <td><a href="/budgets/<%= index %>"><%= budgetItem.name %></a></td>
          <td><%= budgetItem.amount %></td>
        </tr>
        <% }) %>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer');-%>
```

Second EJS file: show.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column one-half">
      <h1><%= budgetDetail.name %></h1>
      <button type="button">Back</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an absolute path for your public folder.
I use this:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));`

**__dirname** is the directory of the server.js file.
If your public folder is outside that folder, you can simply navigate to te previous
folder with /../

**You need to import "path".**

Comment: thanks Nicolò, while this didn't exactly solve my problem, I discovered that simply adding a backslash to the link tags in the css imports inside the header ejs partial made everything functional again. I guess it just wasn't referencing the root folder.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/skeleton.css">`